# New files in /var/www have the wrong permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

My web root, `/var/www`, is owned by my personal user on the system, however I have also set up an FTP user with `/var/www` as its home directory.

If I put new files in `/var/www` via SSH logged in as either user (`nano /var/www/something.html`) everything is fine and new files recieve permissions 644, which is what I want. New directories put in via `mkdir` also work fine through each user and recieve permissions 755, also what I want.

The problem is that if I put new files in it via FTP, through either user, they recieve permissions 600, which is not what I want. Directories recieve permissions 700.

So how do I fix it so new files recieve the permissions I want? I am using vsftpd as an FTP server, if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration file of /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
#anon_umask=066
anon_umask=022

chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=ftp
```

(ftp whatever user you want them to be)

Look at /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf.example and read examples. It is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks! I'd been banging my head against permissions that seemed to be correct but still wouldn't work. I should have known it would have been in a config file.

Comment: wouldn't hurt to also run a cron task with a script to verify the permissions say once an hour or so. As root.